# How to efficiently fetch data and count rows in one swing?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-performance

Say you've got a table with millions of records - let's call each one an "*item*".
The table has some columns including one boolean column - let's call it `isProcessed` - and one with an e-mail-address of the worker who porcessed the item - let's call it `worker`.

Let's say, worker John Smith (john.smith@example.org) invokes an event which shall return **(1) all unprocessed items** (`isProcessed` = false) on the one hand and **(2) the number of items processed by John** on the other.

My first idea was to simply do two queries, one fetching the items and a second one counting all items processed by John.

But that seems rather inefficient, because I need to iterate twice over all millions of records. I could also iterate over each row and check both columns `isProcessed` and `worker` at once, so I don't run the table twice.

In terms of code performance, which approach is more efficient in SQL? Or more generally, which approach is recommended?

Comment: Ambiguous.  Is "(1)" the items assigned to John, but not yet processed?  Or is it a count?  Or is it all unprocessed items (and "John" is irrelevant to "(1)".)  Please clarify.

Comment: @RickJames, no, "(1)" and "(2)" are simply to indicate in this question that two things need to be done. The numbers do not have anything to do with the operation(s) itself.

Comment: Is it all unprocessed items for John?  Or all unprocessed items for everyone.  (The solution is radically different.)

Comment: Latter - all unprocessed items can be processed by anyone. That's why there is an e-mail-address to itentify who processed an item.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one query:

```
select count(*) as NumProcessed, sum(isProcessed = 0) as NumUnprocessed
from t
where worker = 'john.smith@example.org';
```

Comment: I don't think there are any 'unprocessed' items by 'john', since 'john' is applied only when 'john' processes it.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. There are no unprocessed items without an e-mail-address. **But** I did not mean the number of unprocessed items, but the respective rows themselves. So instead of `select count(*) ...`, it would need to be `select * ... where isProcessed = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding a clause such as this:

```
SUM(IF(worker='john', 1, 0)) AS johncount
```

This will effectively count the number of times 'John' is the `worker` in a row.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the indexes, and whether they are useful.

Generally "flags" (isProcessed) are not useful to index since their 'cardinality' is not good.  Instead it is simpler and (usually) faster to simply do a table scan.  Hence, `INDEX(isProcessed)` is likely to be useless.

OTOH, `worker='John'` may be useful.  But not if John processes a quarter of the items.  So, it is dubious whether `INDEX(worker)` would be useful.

If both indexes were useful, then this would be the speedup:

```
( SELECT 'unprocessed' AS x, COUNT(*) AS ct FROM tbl WHERE isProcessed = false )
UNION ALL
( SELECT 'processed' AS x, COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE worker = 'John');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider maintaining a lookup table `t` with two columns, `worker` and `processed_count`, counting the number of processed items per worker. This table could be kept in sync by triggers and would contain a single row with `worker = NULL` (or some *magic text*) to keep the number unprocessed items.

Then you could

`SELECT processed_count FROM t AS unprocessed WHERE worker IS NULL`

and

`SELECT processed_count FROM t AS processed_by_john WHERE worker='john'`

The table would grow linearly with the number of workers and could be index organized if you have a lot of workers.